# Box class, getFull() method will not display accurate boolean result

Tags: java, class, methods, driver, box

Design and implement a class called Box that contains instance data that represents the height, width, and depth of the box. Also include a boolean variable called full as instance data that represents if the box is full or not. Define the Box constructor to accept and initialize the height, width, and depth of the box.

Each newly created Box is empty (the constructor should initialize full to false). Include getter and setter methods for all instance data. Include a toString method that returns a one-line description of the box. A driver, main method that instantiates and updates several Box objects is provided for testing purposes.

However, I have attempted to make my getFull() method to tell if the dimensions multiply out to 125, which they do not. The getFull() method still displays that it is true that the box is full, which is wrong.

***Box class:***

```
package BoxClass;

public class Box {

double height, width, depth;
boolean full;
private double fullbox = 125.0;

public Box(double height_double, double width_double, double depth_double) //Constructor
{
    height = height_double;
    width = width_double;
    depth = depth_double;
    full = false;
}
public boolean Full()
{
    return(true);
}
public double getHeight() //Getters
{
    return(height);
}
public double getWidth()
{
    return(width);
}
public double getDepth()
{
    return(depth);
}
public boolean getFull()
{
    if(((height)*(width)*(depth)) == (fullbox))
    {
        return(true);
    }
}
public void setHeight(double height2) //Setters
{
    height = height2;
}
public void setWidth(double width2)
{
    width = width2;
}
public void setDepth(double depth2)
{
    depth = depth2;
}
public void setFull(boolean full2)
{
    full = full2;
}
public String toString()
{
    return("Height: " + height + "| Width: " + width + "| Depth: " + depth + " | Full? " + Full());
}

}
```

***Driver class:***

```
package BoxClass;

public class BoxTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Box obj1, obj2, obj3;

    obj1 = new Box(2.05,2.05,0.05);
    obj2 = new Box(3.06,0.08,1.54);
    obj3 = new Box(0.05,2.06,2.09);

    System.out.println(obj1);
    System.out.println(obj2);
    System.out.println(obj3);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in this method:

```
public String toString()
{
    return("Height: " + height + "| Width: " + width + "| Depth: " + depth + " | Full? " + Full());
}
```

You are calling the **Full()** method, which is a method that always returns ***true***. The method you want to call is **getFull()**.